# Graph minimal cycles

Tags: graphs

Given a graph ***G***, we say ***C*** a cycle of ***G*** such that however we take two nodes *a* and *b* of ***C***, there is NOT a path between *a* and *b* in ***G\edges(C)*** (that is the graph ***G*** less the edges of ***C***).

Is ***C*** a minimal cycle of ***G***? If it's not, what is the name of such a cycle?

Comment: The minimal "circle" (by your definition) is the empty set

Comment: @nirshahar No; for example if you have a graph ***G*** that is a square (nodes *a, b, c, d* and edges *ab, bc, cd, da*) with the diagonal *ac*, then the cycle *abc* is a minimal cycle, in fact if you remove the edges *ab, bc, ca* from ***G***, there are no paths between the nodes *a,b,c*. I'm sorry, in the original question I have used 'circle' instead 'cycle'.

Comment: The definition of a cycle is a bit different that what you wrote. The definition im familiar with states that $C$ is a cycle if it represents a simple path starting from some node and ending in it as well

Comment: Are you considering the usual definition of cycle (as in the Wikipedia page), or by the definition that you wrote in the body of the question?

Comment: @nirshahar I use the usual definition of cycle: 'non-empty trail in which the only repeated vertices are the first and last vertices'. Wikipedia says that a cycle, with the properties that I have described, is a [chordless_cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)).

Comment: @MarioGiambarioli. What you describe is not equivalent to a chordless cycle. In particular all cycles with your property are chordless, but not all chordless cycles have your property. Consider for example the graph $G=(\{1,2,3,4,5\}, \{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1), (1,5), (5,4)\})$ and the cycle $C=\langle 1,2,3,4,1 \rangle$. $C$ is chordless but it does not have your property since $G \setminus C$ contains the path $\langle 1,5,4 \rangle$ and $1,4$ are vertices of $C$.